The release version of my project in Monogame Android has SpriteFont
In the debug version, the object is initialized and the text is displayed.But in the release version, initialization causes an error, and the build stops.monogame Android does not start
I tried to clean up and rebuild the project in VS.I rebuilt the files in MGCB editor. everything is identical in obj/debug/content and obj/release/content
No matter what I do, the mistake remains.I really need help!
P.S. I found out that this is happening because of the AOT compilation

So, did you answer your question? If so, you can add an answer and mark it as accepted after 48h.
